# how to update price instantaneously for an order form (html/javascript)

Tags: javascript, xhtml

so what I need to do is somehow make my form update its price instantly.
The validator that the professor has provided does a check when you click the check button it automatically fills in blanks and selects the price, and the size (one size only).

here is the xhtml:

```
<select name='shirts' size='2'  onchange='calculateItemPrice()'>
    <option value='Shirts Size'> Shirt Size</option>
    <option value='Small'>Small Shirt</option>
    <option value='Medium'>Medium shirt</option>
    <option value='Large'>Large shirt</option>
    <option value='xLarge'>xLarge shirt</option>
</select>
```

*heres the problem*: using the validator if i click check Small size, it fills all the blanks on the form and auto selects Small Shirt...but the price does not update. However, if i click on any other of the check it buttons on the prof's website (check Medium/Large/xLarge) it fills everything in and selects the appropriate size and updates the price.
so my issue seems to only be with the Small size.

now the calculation function works(was provided by prof) if the user manually selects a size.

I don't know if I need to do something with the HTML or with my select function from javascript, heres the code (someone asked a question on here earlier that resolved my problem but the question has been removed so I don't know if I made a mistake)

```
function validatefield05(errMessages)
{

   if(document.sizes.shirts.selectedIndex ==0)        
      {
        errMessages +="<li class='b1'>You must Select a Size</li>\n";
      }

    if(!document.sizes.shirts.value)     
      {
        errMessages +="<li class='b1'>You must Select a Size</li>\n";
      }
   return errMessages;
}
```

I've tried messing around with the ==0 making it 1/2 and such but that would result in not being able to choose one of the options.

Any idea's and/or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

***this is not an assignment just an exercise to practice for exams next week***

Comment: I dont know why, whenever I say "Hi folks" it doesn't show up lol.

Comment: Dude! you don't have _"small size"_! you have _small Shirt_ or _Shirt size_! ?!

Comment: woops good catch sorry i copied from my notepad instead of my vi editor its suppose to be sizes LOL.

Comment: SO is programmed to try and reduce noise. "Hi Folks" at the beginning of your question means that on the home page in the preview, people see "Hi Folks" in the preview instead of the beginnings of your actual question. Imagine how utterly useless the front page would be if it had questions and then question previews that said "Hi", "Greetings", "Yo whaddup dawg", etc. It's very similar to why question titles that say "Help!" are useless.

Comment: If you're going to supply a link, great. Otherwise please make sure the description of the problem is **exactly** accurate. A listing of your `calculateItemPrice()` function would be useful, too.

Answer (score 1):

Your code works onChange, so you probably just need to add a default option:

```
<select name='sizes' size='2'  onchange='calculateItemPrice()'>
    <option value=""> Choose size </option>  <=========
    <option value='Shirts'> Shirt Size</option>
    <option value='Small'>Small Shirt</option>
    <option value='Medium'>Medium shirt</option>
    <option value='Large'>Large shirt</option>
    <option value='xLarge'>xLarge shirt</option>
</select>
```

**[LIVE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/L9fLT/1)**

Comment: hmm I tried just now, but it still does the same thing, instead it'll select Shirt Size but it wont say 0.00 in the price field, it'll stay blank. But if I manually select 'Shirt Size' it'll say 0.00. I'm so lost lol

Comment: @Umeed. Can you give us a fiddle just like I did?

Comment: I'm sorry, don't quite follow what you mean. ?

Comment: @Umeed. Give me a link to a demo, just like I did in the answer.

Comment: OH okay just a moment didnt see live demo there